# How to list multiple integers in define?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I defined  watermelon to 1 like so

```
#define watermelon 1
```

But how do I define it with 2 as well? So it will look something like this.

```
    #define watermelon 1 and 2.

  //of course this isn't how it is done.//
```

I forgot how this is done. I am having  a huge brain fart. Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean combine? `&&` ???

Comment: Yes so watermelon will equal 1 and 2.

Comment: Mickey, watermelon can't be equal to 1 and 2 at the same time, since 1 and 2 are not equal. Unless your maths is _far_ more advanced than mine, you need to step back and rethink what you're trying to do :-)

Comment: @mickeymouse a number can't be equal to 1 **and** 2 at the same time...

Answer (score 3):

That's not generally something you do. Generally, one "symbol" refers to one value.

What you *can* do, is to create two different symbols:

```
#define MELON_A 1
#define MELON_B 2
```

and then use code like:

```
if ((fruitType == MELON_A) || (fruitType == MELON_B)) ...
```

If you'd like to step back and tell us the *problem* you're trying to solve (rather than a potential *solution* to that problem), we could probably help out with more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum {
MELON_A = 1,
MELON_B,
MELON_C
} MELON;
```

or else you can use enumeration